# Django REST API populate only selected fields from Many to many field

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I have a working API in my project that look something like this :

```
{    
    "id": 1,
        "project_name": "Project A",
        "user": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "employee_id": "001",
                "official_name": "RAY PAlMER",
                "nick_name": "RAY",
                "date_of_birth": "1965-08-25",
                "gender": "1",
                "race": "CAUCASIAN",
                "food_pref": "Vegetarian",
           },
           {
                    "id": 3,
                    "employee_id": "002",
                    "official_name": "LAIRA OMOTO",
                    "nick_name": "LAIRA",
                    "date_of_birth": "1990-01-15",
                    "gender": "2",
                    "race": "WHITE",
                    "food_pref": "Any",
          }
        ]
}
```

The `user` field is a foreign key field and its populating everything from its source model called `Employee`. My question is how can I populate the `user` many to many field with only several field that I wanted to get from the `Employee` Model. For example I just want to populate only a user id, official name, and gender, therefore the output should be something like this

```
{    
    "id": 1,
        "project_name": "Project A",
        "user": [
            {
                "id": 3,
                "official_name": "RAY PAlMER",
                "gender": "1",
           },
           {
                    "id": 4,
                    "official_name": "LAIRA",
                    "gender": "2",
           }
        ]
}
```

Below is my source code :

Project Model :

```
class Project(models.Model):
    user = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, blank=True)
```

Employee Model :

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    official_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    gender_choice = (
                    ('male', 'Male'),
                    ('female', 'Female')
                    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=gender_choice,  null=True, 
    blank=True)
```

Serializer :

```
    class MarketingReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Project
            fields = ('id', 'project_name','user')
            depth = 1
```

Any help is much appreciated thanks!

API :

```
    class MarketingReportAPI(APIView):
        def get(self, request):
            all_projects = Project.objects.all()
            project_serializer = MarketingReportSerializer(all_projects, many=True)
            return Response(project_serializer.data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create `EmployeeSerializer` serializer.

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = ('id', 'official_name', 'gender')
```

Now use it in your `MarketingReportSerializer`

```
class MarketingReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = EmployeeSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('id', 'project_name', 'user')
```

And then you can use `MarketingReportSerializer` in your view.

Comment: Hi this works! Thanks for both of you @Satendra and @Ankita!